# Trying to set viewBox width / height dynamically

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I am trying to use React Native Animated to zoom into an SVG programmatically.
At the moment I am testing out code, proving some things out.
I can't seem to pass in the viewBox sizes that are set using React.useState(new Animated.Value(0)

I get an error: Invalid `viewBox` prop:0 0 [object Object][object Object]

Here are some pieces of my code:

`const AnimatedSVG = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Svg);`

`const [widthValue, setWidthValue] = React.useState(new Animated.Value(1920));`

`const [heightValue, setHeightValue] = React.useState(new Animated.Value(1080));`

```
const segmentClick = (event, someParameter) => {
      Animated.timing(widthValue, {
        toValue: 3000,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true,
        easing: Easing.linear,
      }).start();
  };
```

`` <AnimatedSVG x="0px" y="0px" viewBox={`0 0 ${widthValue} ${heightValue}`} style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1080; "> ``

As mentioned the error I get: Invalid `viewBox` prop:0 0 [object Object][object Object]
It seems widthValue and widthHeight are objects.
But if I console.log them I can see them printed out as 1920 / 1080

I suspect I'm missing something quite simple, but can't find the answer online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try create a listener to animated value, and update a state:

```
const [widthValue, setWidthValue] = React.useState(1920);
const widthAnimated = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(1920)).current;

const segmentClick = (event, someParameter) => {
      widthAnimated.addListener((e) => setWidthValue(e.value)) // Add listener
      Animated.timing(widthAnimated, {
        toValue: 3000,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true,
        easing: Easing.linear,
      }).start();
};
```

In SVG:

```
<AnimatedSVG x="0px" y="0px" viewBox={`0 0 ${widthValue} ${heightValue}`} style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1080; ">
```

Do the same thing to height.

Comment: This seems to do the same thing. widthAnimated is an object.

Comment: Yes, but you going to use in SVG a "pure" state now

Comment: The widthValue now is not a `Animated.Value`, but just a number

Comment: Ok how do I use that to set the viewBox width from widthAnimated?
```<AnimatedSVG x="0px" y="0px" viewBox={`0 0 ${widthAnimated} ${heightAnimated}`} style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1080; " opacity={opacityValue}>```

Comment: In SVG you still going to use the variable widthValue. But, I transform it in a number not `Animated.Value`

Comment: So, use the SVG of same way you've used before

Comment: Thanks. Things load now but still a problem though. In the segmentClick I console.log widthAnimated and widthValue and they are both showing 1920. So I don't see anything change size on the screen upon clicking. I don't see it getting set to 3000.

Comment: I stand corrected. This does work. The animation is just very slow. Which I believe is due to a heavy SVG.